# Upper/Lower case discrepancy in Git and SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I've been maintaining a repo via source tree and I've come across an issue where a single file seems to have two references to it – one in lowercase and one in uppercase.
This came about after I changed the case of the title a while back. If I try deleting one, both are removed, and if I try committing them both, one always remains in the working copy.

I have tried `mv` on the file to see if I could force it to use just uppercase, but I still have the issue of the duplicate reference.

If anyone has a solution (and an explanation of what is happening), I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [similar issue with renamed file when using SourceTree](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/SOURCETREEKB/Renaming+File+Under+Git+Source+Control+is+not+Noticed+by+SourceTree).

The usual workaround is to fall back to command line and:

> for instance if you want to rename "`kh.png`" to "`KH.png`", go to your git repo from command line and do:

```
mv kh.png temp.png 
# (or "mv KH.png temp.png" if kh.png as already been renamed to KH.png under Source Tree)
git add -A
git commit -m "renaming kh.png to KH.png"
mv temp.png KH.png
git add -A
git commit --amend -m "Renamed file.txt to File.txt"
```

Comment: Nice. I was sort of close, but I kept trying to rename the file to the upper/lower case opposite. Changing it to something else entirely was the way to go – thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this issue in the source tree. Follow bellow steps

1. Change the capitalization of the "file" name and add "1" to the end (or
   other symbols)
2. Stage (without commit) = result "File1" - renaming files Remove "1"
   from the end
3. Stage (without commit) = result "File" - renaming files (only
   capitalization now)
4. Do commit.